# "The control sequence at the end of the top line was never defined ..."

Tags: tabularx

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth} { 
  | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X 
  | >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X | }
 \hline
 item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
 \hline
 item 21  & item 22  & item 23  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I have tried to compile it on TeXshop with this error: undefined control sequence...l.15\end{tabular}
It is compilable on overleaf however, but with three warning pointing to the same error.  Anyidea what I did wrong?

Comment: move \usepackage{arydshln} after tabularx.

Comment: I have wasted half a day tring to figure out what went wrong!!!! Thanks your so much.Would you mind putting it in the answer so I could select it? Also, do you happen to know why the choice of compiler affect the result of compilation? Isn't it supposed to be the underlying LaTeX that interprete the source code?

Comment: also when asking about an error it helps if you show the error message from the log. The first line of the error message here will show which command is not defined but you did not show it,

Comment: Sorry. Will do it next time! ( and I suspect I will turn to TeX.se for help pretty soon!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation of `arydshln` points out:

> arydshln has to be loaded after array, longtable, colortab and/or colortbl

and

> reversing the order of \usepackage will cause some mysterious error

tabularx loads the `array` package, and so should come before `arydshln`.